# Botão que expande no hover com CSS Transition

Tags: html, css, css3

Estou tentando fazer um botão, que no `hover` ele se expanda e mostre o resto do botão.

Aqui tem um exemplo do que quero fazer (o botão é um simples `<h2>`):

```
h2:before {
  content: 'Testando';
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-weight: normal;
  -webkit-transition:width 0.2s;
  transition: width 0.2s;
  padding:10px;
  width:100px;
  float:left; 
}
h2:hover:before {
  width:200px;
  content: 'Testando o botão';
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/FKXWF/1/**

Mas como dá pra perceber, no `hover` o restinho do botão aparece meio torto...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma das soluções possíveis é forçar que o texto dentro do botão ocupe só uma linha. Você pode fazer isso adicionando `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden` no seu botão:

```
h2:before {
  content: 'Testando';
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-weight: normal;
  -webkit-transition:width 0.2s;
  transition: width 0.2s;
  padding:10px;
  width:100px;
  float:left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
h2:hover:before {
  width:200px;
  content: 'Testando o botão';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FKXWF/2/